# IIS suddenly serving garbled UTF-8

Tags: asp.net, iis, encoding, utf-8, configuration

I was working on a website. All files are UTF-8 encoded without BOM. Everything was working fine. Suddenly my IIS or ASP.NET started serving the files with all umlauts garbled.

file contents of .aspx file on webserver

> öäü

returned to browser by IIS

> Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼

I can "fix" this problem by re-saving the files as **UTF-8 with BOM** but I don't want to do that. The HTTP Response header claims the content is UTF-8

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
```

but it is not. If I create an identical file and change it's extension from .aspx to .html, it gets served correctly.

This isn't restricted to a single website running on IIS but it's happening on ALL websites running on the IIS server. It not some setting in the web.config, it's happening even when I completely delete the web.config.

What could have caused this and why is this happening?

**EDIT**

OK so turns out I had to add `<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />` to the web.config after all, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

fixed it. It's strange because I'm pretty sure I didn't have that setting in my web.config before.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as you said. `DotNet Globalization` feature page is responsible for configuring `DotNet Framework globalization` settings, such as language, culture, encoding options.
We can change globalization settings for ASP.NET applications at the Web server level when we want to apply to all ASP.NET applications on the server.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831368(v=ws.11)
You could post your solution as an answer to help the guy that runs into the same issue.